# why "java" section in memory profiler consuming lot of memory?

Tags: android

Java section in profiler consuming lot of memory on simple navigation. This results in an application crash. Any help would be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `application crash.` with an exception and stacktrace, which will show where the problem is.

Comment: i am getting this error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 39137548 byte allocation with 10959848 free bytes and 10MB until OOM

Comment: and the stacktrace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android OutOfMemoryError:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012006/android-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Are you using any high resolution image in your app?

Comment: @Piyush yes i am using but am releasing memory on onDestroy. but still getting same issue.

Comment: Load your image with Glide because if you are loading image from drawable folder and if it's a high resolution image then it will throw above error.

Comment: am using Picasso library.

Comment: Show your image. What's the resolution of it?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a "memory leak". Yes, I know that in java garbage collector exist - but it is possible to create a memory leak. 
Please use Memory Analyzer Tool to find and resolve leaks.